# Searching with the name parameter of the Type.GetMember method

Tags: c#, syntax, parameters, wildcard, system.reflection

I am currently aware that the first parameter of all method overloads for the [Type.GetMember Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmember.aspx):

> *name*
>
> Type: System.String 
>       The string containing the name of the public
>   members to get.

is case-sensitive and it allows searching by matching:

1. the *exact* member name

   ```
   Type myType = myString.GetType();
   // Get the members for myString which are named Compare.
   MemberInfo[] myMembers = myType.GetMember("Compare");
   ```
2. all member names that *begin* with a given value, by using the `*` wildcard

   ```
   Type myType = myString.GetType();
   // Get the members for myString starting with the letter C.
   MemberInfo[] myMembers = myType.GetMember("C*");
   // Get the members for myString starting with the string Comp.
   myMembers = myType.GetMember("Comp*");
   ```

You can even get all available members if you use only `*` as the parameter value.

My question is: **besides the 2 approaches above, is it possible to have some other type of string pattern for matching the members (i.e. such as `C*e` or `Compar?`?)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the .NET Framework code does not contain processing for any other wildcard.

The code from `System.RuntimeType.FilterHelper` that is used internally by `GetMember`:

```
// System.RuntimeType
private static void FilterHelper(BindingFlags bindingFlags, ref string name, bool allowPrefixLookup, out bool prefixLookup, out bool ignoreCase, out RuntimeType.MemberListType listType)
{
    prefixLookup = false;
    ignoreCase = false;
    if (name != null)
    {
        if ((bindingFlags & BindingFlags.IgnoreCase) != BindingFlags.Default)
        {
            name = name.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            ignoreCase = true;
            listType = RuntimeType.MemberListType.CaseInsensitive;
        }
        else
        {
            listType = RuntimeType.MemberListType.CaseSensitive;
        }
        if (allowPrefixLookup && name.EndsWith("*", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 1);
            prefixLookup = true;
            listType = RuntimeType.MemberListType.All;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listType = RuntimeType.MemberListType.All;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, do you have any reference / link for this method definition?